# Checking if a filename exists in a directory with Javascript/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm writing a Javascript function for a PHP form that searches and confirms that a file exists before the user submits it. The filename that needs to be checked depends on what the user enters into the form, so I retrieved the values entered by the user using:

```
var getthis = getElementByName('name').value;
```

Here are all of the strings:

```
    var firstname = getElementByName('first').value;
    var lastname = getElementByName('last').value;
    var id = getElementByName('id').value;
    var seperator = " ";
    var app = "_app.txt";
```

Then I concatenate them:

```
var filename = firstname.concat(lastname, seperator, id, app);
```

Now I'm trying to compare the name of an existing file with the data the user entered which I collected in the variables. Is there anyway that I can check a directory for a file name? Also am I even using the concat() function properly?

Comment: [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) , you cannot let interfere client side to server side, without security breach.

Comment: this is probably way easyer to do in php with file_exists <?php
$filename = '/path/to/foo.txt';

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "The file $filename exists";
} else {
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}
?>

Answer (score 0):

It is not most elegant but:

```
<?php
$filename = '/path/to/foo.txt';

if (file_exists($filename)) {
?>

<script>
    myVar = "The file exists";
</script>

<?php
} else {
?>

<script>
     myVar = "The file does not exist";
</script>

<?php
}
?>
```

Then you output your var with js

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding this - could you elaborate?

Comment: this is setting a js var encapsulated with php, you should go use ajax and post the `var filename` to php , then based on the `$_POST` to the php file you get returned true/false, so... forget my answer and investigate jQuery [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)